# How to load balance read-only request to master,slave db MySQL server?

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, connection-pooling, master-slave

Can i configure MySQL request or db pool property(currently using c3p0) to load balance read-only request to db server,i read from somewhere it said that you can do this by set request as read-only flag (on application level),which can be troublesome because it mean i need to change code in the whole legacy system.

So is there anyway to congigure MySQL connection,db pool to let it auto loadbalance read-only connection without touching the application code,thx for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MySQL-Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/) and read/write splitting, e.g. explained at [MySQL Proxy learns R/W Splitting](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/mysql-proxy-learns-r-w-splitting/) and [MySQL Proxy: more R/W splitting](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/mysql-proxy-more-r-w-splitting/) in principle.